# React state one step behind despite useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a React form for user login, everything works fine except for a setting a successful or unsuccessful message. Once i login, i set the value of a `useState variable [res, setRes]` to either successful or usuccessful depending on whether the user is registered or not. Problem is, even if the user is registered and username and password is correct, i get the message "invalid credentials" at least and most once. Subsequent calls from the same user result in the correct message being displayed. I searched and found that state is one step behind, and the solution is to use `useEffect`, but i am already using it. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is? Code is as follows

```
export const Login = () => {
    const email = useField('string')
    const password = useField('password')
    const [cred, setCred] = useState({})
    const send = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setCred({'email':email.value, 'password':password.value}) 
            showToast()
    }
    const [toastIsShown, setToastIsShown] = useState(false);

    const showToast = () => {
        setToastIsShown(true);
    }
    const [res,setRes] = useState('')

    const hook = () => {
        axios
        .post('http://localhost:5000/auth', cred)
        .then(response => { 
            console.log('response is ',response.data)
            setRes('Login Successful')
    })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("error is ",err.response)
            setRes('Invalid username or password')
        })
    }
    useEffect(hook,[cred])
    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit = {send}>
                <IonText>Enter Name</IonText>
                <br />
                <input {...email} />
                <br />
                <IonText>Enter Password</IonText>
                <br />
                <input {...password} />
                <br />
                <button>Send</button>
            </form>
            <IonToast
                        isOpen={toastIsShown}
                        onDidDismiss={() => setToastIsShown(false)}
                        message={res}
                        duration={3000}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

I am using Ionic, which is why you see Toast there. Also, the language is Typescript.
Thanks

Comment: The initial state of `cred` is an empty object because of `const [cred, setCred] = useState({})`. If that is invalid credentials, you will always get one invalid call. Should the hook only get called when there are valid credentials?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No the hook can be called with or without valid credentials.

Comment: I tried hardcoding a valid username password for ```cred``` but same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook is *always* called when a component mounts, and after that every time a value in its dependency array changes. Since an empty object is presumably not a valid log in, you're always going to get an unsuccessful attempt when the component mounts. You could do some simple validation like:

```
cred.email && cred.password && axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', cred)...
```

However, the root of the problem is that you are misusing `useEffect`. A log-in attempt is (usually, and in your case) a one time event, not a side-effect that occurs as the result of previous significant action. The side-effect in this scenario happens *after* the log-in attempt, when you trigger a Toast which contains a notification about the result:

```
export const Login = () => {
    const email = useField('string');
    const password = useField('password');
    
    const [res, setRes] = useState('');
    const [toastIsShown, setToastIsShown] = useState(false);

    const send = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const cred = {
            email: email.value,
            password: password.value
        };

        axios
        .post('http://localhost:5000/auth', cred)
        .then(response => { 
            console.log('response is ',response.data)
            setRes('Login Successful');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("error is ",err.response)
            setRes('Invalid username or password');
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        res && setToastIsShown(true);
    }, [res]);
    
    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

This is just to demonstrate a more reasonable use of `useEffect`. In reality I would probably not even use one here and instead just call `setToastIsShown` from inside `send` after setting `res`. A `useEffect` really comes in handy when you have two correlated pieces of data which are updated by multiple uncorrelated methods.